# How I can I use an ID selector that contains a '#' in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="content">
<textarea id="#example-1">
</textarea>
<textarea id="#example-2">
</textarea>
</div>
```

and Jquery

```
var xyz = $("content##example-1").val();
```

This code doesn't work for me. It crashes - shows undefined. When I delete "#" from div from textarea and one "#" from JS code it works. It need to works with id with "#".
Can I put variable into $() after quotation marks? E.g.:

```
$("content#"variable)
```

Comment: The # character is not valid for HTML name or id attribute vaules in HTML 4. It is allowed in HTML5 and using it as an ID value isn't an issue in current browsers. However, it will fool selector engines that expect it to be a token indicating that the following characters are an element ID. The selector `content#example` will try to match an element with tag name *content* and id of *example*. There is no such element in HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Escape the special character in the ID](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F), and remove that `content` part. Because [element IDs must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), an ID selector will match *at most* one element. Therefore, anything beyond that is overspecified.

```
var xyz = $("#\\#example-1").val();
```

Better still, don't use a special character in the ID at all:

```
<div id="content">
    <textarea id="example-1">
    </textarea>
    <textarea id="example-2">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

```
var xyz = $('#example-1').val();
```

---

> how about $("content#"variable)? Is it possible? Is it exist any possibility to deal with it?

That's not valid JavaScript; you need to use string concatenation. Also, the selector `'content'` matches elements with tag name `content`, which is not what you want. Believe me: just get rid of the `content` part entirely.

Then use the `jq` function described in the jQuery FAQ that I linked.

```
var xyz = $(jq(variable)).val();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot :) But how about $("content#"variable)? Is it possible? Is it exist any possibility to deal with it?

Comment: You sure that'll work cross browser? I'm pretty sure a `#` isn't a valid ID character before HTML5.

Comment: I know but now i'm using Jquery ui tabs and now I don't have time to delete "#" from `jquery.ui.tabs.js`.

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski _"don't have time to delete '#' from ..."_ what in the ***world*** are you talking about?

Comment: :) I can't deal with it and i think that i need some time to deal with "#" in `jquery.ui.tabs.js`.

Comment: Unless you have made other changes, you absolutely do not need to edit that file, I promise you. Just remove the `#`s from the IDs **in your HTML** and adjust the selectors in **your** code accordingly.

Comment: I'm using "simple manipulation" from jquery exapmle :) I need to do this becouse: i'm getting the id from href, I can't edit in my file becouse, "#" is setting outside the code. Why? when I'm delete from `tabTemplate` "#", it replace to "ui-" (in `href`) :) This is like fighting with windmills :)