# In Jquery selector,what if I want to provide a variable that contains the elementId generating at run time

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following code snippet:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#input1").contextMenu({
        menu: 'myMenu'
        },
         function(action, el, pos) {
          alert("clicked");
    });
```

The above code is not working coz input1 is a variable that contains the elementId generating at run time.

Suppose input1 is generating as follows:

var input1 = "input"+j;
where j is a variable having value 0

Please guide how can i use variable input1 as a elementId in jQuery selector.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Try maybe posting some markup or more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string concatenation to form the selector:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#" + input1).contextMenu({
    menu: 'myMenu'
    },
     function(action, el, pos) {
      alert("clicked");
});
```

Obviously this assumes that the variable `input1` exists and has the desired value when that code is executed.

Comment: lol. I never would have guessed that was what he was asking for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I will try your suggestion.                                           I have also read in one of the related questions about jq like $(jq(variable)). What is this jq? Any idea.

Comment: @Infotechie Can you link the question that's from? From the code it looks like `jq` is a function, but I can't tell you **what** it does.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676704/how-i-can-i-use-an-id-selector-that-contains-a-in-jquery                                              Please refer answer of MДΓΓ БДLL.

Comment: @Infotechie All the information about that is already available in that answer. Click the link at the very start of the answer for an explanation of what the `jq()` function does.

Comment: @Anthony sorry to bother.Somehow I missed that part. Thanks.